# append based on '%' sign pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, split, append

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEwgG.png)

I am trying to extract values with '%' from these a,b,c,d columns and put into the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with an example for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan,'daw','50%'], 'b':['3%', '4%',np.nan]})
df.a = df.a.apply(lambda x: np.nan if not '%' in str(x) else x)
df.b = df.b.apply(lambda x: np.nan if not '%' in str(x) else x)
df['result'] = [df.a[i] if df.a[i] is not np.nan else df.b[i] for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

This will give you this:

```
    a   b   result
0   NaN 3%  3%
1   NaN 4%  4%
2   50% NaN 50%
```

Please see if this works for you.